# How do I split a tab of JTabbedPane into its own window?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtabbedpane

I have an application I've made whose initial GUI consists of a JTabbedPane with multiple tabs. I want to take one of those tabs and separate it from its parent JTabbedPane, making it its own window. Is there a way other than making a new JFrame, copying the tab's contents and then changing all the method calls?

Comment: Start with the code seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18587746/418556).

Comment: Oh, no, I don't want to drag the tab away, I want to open the application with two windows already, it's just that the content of the second window is the - current - content of one of the tabs.