# Drag JTabbedpane out to window and automatic create new JFrame

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtabbedpane

Good morning,

First my mission is want to make my JTabbedPane Drag-out to window and create new JFrame. Illustration is like NetBeans / SublimeText,

I Found reference for drag & drop JTabbedPane in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61982 , It is success to drag and drop Tab from 1 JTabbedPane or 2/many JTabbedPane

now what i want is whenever drag-out tab the document, it automatic create new Frame and insert tab to new jtabbedPane.  And If the jtabbedpane is empty / no-component, the jframe is automatic closed.

--

"Shorted Question"
Can i have, when I drag tab (from jtabbedpane) to desktop/outside JFrame and automatic create JFrame & Tabbedpane inside then placed the tab there ?

Also When the tab drag&drop and there is none component in jtabbedpane, it's can automatic dispose the JFrame/JTabbedPane.

"Very Shorted Question"
How can i get my JTabbedPane like Netbeans TabbedPane Document Editor ?

--

I Include the file my latest Modified Drag & Drop JTabbedPane with Close Button.

Thank you very much. R.

```
public class DnDCloseButtonTabbedPane extends JTabbedPane {

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int LINEWIDTH = 3;
    private static final String NAME = "TabTransferData";
    private final DataFlavor FLAVOR = new DataFlavor(
            DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType, NAME);
    private static GhostGlassPane s_glassPane = new GhostGlassPane();

    private boolean m_isDrawRect = false;
    private final Rectangle2D m_lineRect = new Rectangle2D.Double();

    private final Color m_lineColor = new Color(0, 100, 255);
    private TabAcceptor m_acceptor = null;

    private final DropTarget dropTarget;

    private final ImageIcon icon;
    private final Dimension buttonSize;

    public DnDCloseButtonTabbedPane() {
        super();
        final DragSourceListener dsl = new DragSourceListener() {
            @Override
            public void dragEnter(DragSourceDragEvent e) {
                e.getDragSourceContext().setCursor(DragSource.DefaultMoveDrop);
            }

            @Override
            public void dragExit(DragSourceEvent e) {
                e.getDragSourceContext()
                        .setCursor(DragSource.DefaultMoveNoDrop);
                m_lineRect.setRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
                m_isDrawRect = false;
                s_glassPane.setPoint(new Point(-1000, -1000));
                s_glassPane.repaint();
//                System.out.println(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void dragOver(DragSourceDragEvent e) {
                //e.getLocation()
                //This method returns a Point indicating the cursor location in screen coordinates at the moment

                TabTransferData data = getTabTransferData(e);

                if (data == null) {
                    e.getDragSourceContext().setCursor(
                            DragSource.DefaultMoveNoDrop);
                    return;
                } // if

                /*
                 Point tabPt = e.getLocation();
                 SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(tabPt, DnDTabbedPane.this);
                 if (DnDTabbedPane.this.contains(tabPt)) {
                 int targetIdx = getTargetTabIndex(tabPt);
                 int sourceIndex = data.getTabIndex();
                 if (getTabAreaBound().contains(tabPt)
                 && (targetIdx >= 0)
                 && (targetIdx != sourceIndex)
                 && (targetIdx != sourceIndex + 1)) {
                 e.getDragSourceContext().setCursor(
                 DragSource.DefaultMoveDrop);

                 return;
                 } // if

                 e.getDragSourceContext().setCursor(
                 DragSource.DefaultMoveNoDrop);
                 return;
                 } // if
                 */
                e.getDragSourceContext().setCursor(
                        DragSource.DefaultMoveDrop);
            }

            public void dragDropEnd(DragSourceDropEvent e) {
                m_isDrawRect = false;
                m_lineRect.setRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
                // m_dragTabIndex = -1;

                if (hasGhost()) {
                    s_glassPane.setVisible(false);
                    s_glassPane.setImage(null);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void dropActionChanged(DragSourceDragEvent e) {

            }
        };

        final DragGestureListener dgl = new DragGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public void dragGestureRecognized(DragGestureEvent e) {
                // System.out.println("dragGestureRecognized");

                Point tabPt = e.getDragOrigin();
                int dragTabIndex = indexAtLocation(tabPt.x, tabPt.y);
                if (dragTabIndex < 0) {
                    return;
                } // if

                initGlassPane(e.getComponent(), e.getDragOrigin(), dragTabIndex);
                try {
                    e.startDrag(DragSource.DefaultMoveDrop,
                            new TabTransferable(DnDCloseButtonTabbedPane.this, dragTabIndex), dsl);
                } catch (InvalidDnDOperationException idoe) {
                    idoe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        //dropTarget =
        dropTarget = new DropTarget(this, DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE,
                new CDropTargetListener(), true);
        new DragSource().createDefaultDragGestureRecognizer(this,
                DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE, dgl);
        m_acceptor = new TabAcceptor() {
            @Override
            public boolean isDropAcceptable(DnDCloseButtonTabbedPane a_component, int a_index) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(Resource.ICON_16X16 + "delete.png"));
        buttonSize = new Dimension(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void addTab(String title, final Component component) {
        JPanel tab = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        tab.setOpaque(false);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(title);
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 4));
        JButton button = new JButton(icon);
        button.setPreferredSize(buttonSize);
        button.setUI(new BasicButtonUI());
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((DnDCloseButtonTabbedPane) component.getParent()).remove(component);
            }
        });
        tab.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);
        tab.add(button, BorderLayout.EAST);
        tab.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 1, 1, 1));
        super.addTab(title, component);
        setTabComponentAt(indexOfComponent(component), tab);
    }

    public TabAcceptor getAcceptor() {
        return m_acceptor;
    }

    public void setAcceptor(TabAcceptor a_value) {
        m_acceptor = a_value;
    }

    private TabTransferData getTabTransferData(DropTargetDropEvent a_event) {
        try {
            TabTransferData data = (TabTransferData) a_event.getTransferable().getTransferData(FLAVOR);
            return data;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private TabTransferData getTabTransferData(DropTargetDragEvent a_event) {
        try {
            TabTransferData data = (TabTransferData) a_event.getTransferable().getTransferData(FLAVOR);
            return data;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private TabTransferData getTabTransferData(DragSourceDragEvent a_event) {
        try {
            TabTransferData data = (TabTransferData) a_event.getDragSourceContext()
                    .getTransferable().getTransferData(FLAVOR);
            return data;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private TabTransferData getTabTransferData(DragSourceDropEvent a_event) {
        try {
            TabTransferData data = (TabTransferData) a_event.getDragSourceContext()
                    .getTransferable().getTransferData(FLAVOR);
            return data;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    class TabTransferable implements Transferable {

        private TabTransferData m_data = null;

        public TabTransferable(DnDCloseButtonTabbedPane a_tabbedPane, int a_tabIndex) {
            m_data = new TabTransferData(DnDCloseButtonTabbedPane.this, a_tabIndex);
        }

        public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) {
            return m_data;
            // return DnDTabbedPane.this;
        }

        public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
            DataFlavor[] f = new DataFlavor[1];
            f[0] = FLAVOR;
            return f;
        }

        public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
            return flavor.getHumanPresentableName().equals(NAME);
        }
    }

    class TabTransferData {

        private DnDCloseButtonTabbedPane m_tabbedPane = null;
        private int m_tabIndex = -1;

        public TabTransferData() {
        }

        public TabTransferData(DnDCloseButtonTabbedPane a_tabbedPane, int a_tabIndex) {
            m_tabbedPane = a_tabbedPane;
            m_tabIndex = a_tabIndex;
        }

        public DnDCloseButtonTabbedPane getTabbedPane() {
            return m_tabbedPane;
        }

        public void setTabbedPane(DnDCloseButtonTabbedPane pane) {
            m_tabbedPane = pane;
        }

        public int getTabIndex() {
            return m_tabIndex;
        }

        public void setTabIndex(int index) {
            m_tabIndex = index;
        }
    }

    private Point buildGhostLocation(Point a_location) {
        Point retval = new Point(a_location);

//        switch (getTabPlacement()) {
//            case JTabbedPane.TOP: {
//                retval.y = 1;
//                retval.x -= s_glassPane.getGhostWidth() / 2;
//            }
//            break;
//
//            case JTabbedPane.BOTTOM: {
//                retval.y = getHeight() - 1 - s_glassPane.getGhostHeight();
//                retval.x -= s_glassPane.getGhostWidth() / 2;
//            }
//            break;
//
//            case JTabbedPane.LEFT: {
//                retval.x = 1;
//                retval.y -= s_glassPane.getGhostHeight() / 2;
//            }
//            break;
//
//            case JTabbedPane.RIGHT: {
//                retval.x = getWidth() - 1 - s_glassPane.getGhostWidth();
//                retval.y -= s_glassPane.getGhostHeight() / 2;
//            }
//            break;
//        } // switch
        retval = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(DnDCloseButtonTabbedPane.this,
                retval, s_glassPane);
        return retval;
    }

    class CDropTargetListener implements DropTargetListener {

        public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent e) {
//             System.out.println("DropTarget.dragEnter: " + DnDCloseButtonTabbedPane.this);

            if (isDragAcceptable(e)) {
                e.acceptDrag(e.getDropAction());
            } else {
                e.rejectDrag();
            } // if
        }

        public void dragExit(DropTargetEvent e) {
//            System.out.println("DropTarget.dragExit: " + DnDCloseButtonTabbedPane.this);
            m_isDrawRect = false;
        }

        public void dropActionChanged(DropTargetDragEvent e) {
        }

        public void dragOver(final DropTargetDragEvent e) {
            TabTransferData data = getTabTransferData(e);

            if (getTabPlacement() == JTabbedPane.TOP
                    || getTabPlacement() == JTabbedPane.BOTTOM) {
                initTargetLeftRightLine(getTargetTabIndex(e.getLocation()), data);
            } else {
                initTargetTopBottomLine(getTargetTabIndex(e.getLocation()), data);
            } // if-else

            repaint();
            if (hasGhost()) {
                s_glassPane.setPoint(buildGhostLocation(e.getLocation()));
                s_glassPane.repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent a_event) {
//             System.out.println("DropTarget.drop: " + DnDTabbedPane.this);

            if (isDropAcceptable(a_event)) {
                convertTab(getTabTransferData(a_event),
                        getTargetTabIndex(a_event.getLocation()));
                a_event.dropComplete(true);
            } else {
                a_event.dropComplete(false);
            } // if-else

            m_isDrawRect = false;
            repaint();
        }

        public boolean isDragAcceptable(DropTargetDragEvent e) {
            Transferable t = e.getTransferable();
            if (t == null) {
                return false;
            } // if

            DataFlavor[] flavor = e.getCurrentDataFlavors();
            if (!t.isDataFlavorSupported(flavor[0])) {
                return false;
            } // if

            TabTransferData data = getTabTransferData(e);

            if (DnDCloseButtonTabbedPane.this == data.getTabbedPane()
                    && data.getTabIndex() >= 0) {
                return true;
            } // if

            if (DnDCloseButtonTabbedPane.this != data.getTabbedPane()) {
                if (m_acceptor != null) {
                    return m_acceptor.isDropAcceptable(data.getTabbedPane(), data.getTabIndex());
                } // if
            } // if

            boolean transferDataFlavorFound = false;
            for (DataFlavor transferDataFlavor : t.getTransferDataFlavors()) {
                if (FLAVOR.equals(transferDataFlavor)) {
                    transferDataFlavorFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (transferDataFlavorFound == false) {
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public boolean isDropAcceptable(DropTargetDropEvent e) {

            Transferable t = e.getTransferable();
            if (t == null) {
                return false;
            } // if

            DataFlavor[] flavor = e.getCurrentDataFlavors();
            if (!t.isDataFlavorSupported(flavor[0])) {
                return false;
            } // if

            TabTransferData data = getTabTransferData(e);

            if (DnDCloseButtonTabbedPane.this == data.getTabbedPane()
                    && data.getTabIndex() >= 0) {
                return true;
            } // if

            if (DnDCloseButtonTabbedPane.this != data.getTabbedPane()) {
                if (m_acceptor != null) {
                    return m_acceptor.isDropAcceptable(data.getTabbedPane(), data.getTabIndex());
                } // if
            } // if

            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean m_hasGhost = true;

    public void setPaintGhost(boolean flag) {
        m_hasGhost = flag;
    }

    public boolean hasGhost() {
        return m_hasGhost;
    }

    /**
     * returns potential index for drop.
     *
     * @param a_point point given in the drop site component's coordinate
     * @return returns potential index for drop.
     */
    private int getTargetTabIndex(Point a_point) {
        boolean isTopOrBottom = getTabPlacement() == JTabbedPane.TOP
                || getTabPlacement() == JTabbedPane.BOTTOM;

        // if the pane is empty, the target index is always zero.
        if (getTabCount() == 0) {
            return 0;
        } // if

        for (int i = 0; i < getTabCount(); i++) {
            Rectangle r = getBoundsAt(i);
            if (isTopOrBottom) {
                r.setRect(r.x - r.width / 2, r.y, r.width, r.height);
            } else {
                r.setRect(r.x, r.y - r.height / 2, r.width, r.height);
            } // if-else

            if (r.contains(a_point)) {
                return i;
            } // if
        } // for

        Rectangle r = getBoundsAt(getTabCount() - 1);
        if (isTopOrBottom) {
            int x = r.x + r.width / 2;
            r.setRect(x, r.y, getWidth() - x, r.height);
        } else {
            int y = r.y + r.height / 2;
            r.setRect(r.x, y, r.width, getHeight() - y);
        } // if-else

        return r.contains(a_point) ? getTabCount() : -1;
    }

    private void convertTab(TabTransferData a_data, int a_targetIndex) {
        DnDCloseButtonTabbedPane source = a_data.getTabbedPane();
//        System.out.println("this=source? " + (this == source));
        int sourceIndex = a_data.getTabIndex();
        if (sourceIndex < 0) {
            return;
        } // if
        //Save the tab's component, title, and TabComponent.
        Component cmp = source.getComponentAt(sourceIndex);
        String str = source.getTitleAt(sourceIndex);
        Component tcmp = source.getTabComponentAt(sourceIndex);

        if (this != source) {
            source.remove(sourceIndex);

            if (a_targetIndex == getTabCount()) {
                addTab(str, cmp);
                setTabComponentAt(getTabCount() - 1, tcmp);
            } else {
                if (a_targetIndex < 0) {
                    a_targetIndex = 0;
                } // if

                insertTab(str, null, cmp, null, a_targetIndex);
                setTabComponentAt(a_targetIndex, tcmp);
            } // if

            setSelectedComponent(cmp);
            return;
        } // if
        if (a_targetIndex < 0 || sourceIndex == a_targetIndex) {
            return;
        } // if
        if (a_targetIndex == getTabCount()) {
            source.remove(sourceIndex);
            addTab(str, cmp);
            setTabComponentAt(getTabCount() - 1, tcmp);
            setSelectedIndex(getTabCount() - 1);
        } else if (sourceIndex > a_targetIndex) {
            source.remove(sourceIndex);
            insertTab(str, null, cmp, null, a_targetIndex);
            setTabComponentAt(a_targetIndex, tcmp);
            setSelectedIndex(a_targetIndex);
        } else {
            source.remove(sourceIndex);
            insertTab(str, null, cmp, null, a_targetIndex - 1);
            setTabComponentAt(a_targetIndex - 1, tcmp);
            setSelectedIndex(a_targetIndex - 1);
        }
    }

    private void initTargetLeftRightLine(int next, TabTransferData a_data) {
        if (next < 0) {
            m_lineRect.setRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
            m_isDrawRect = false;
            return;
        } // if

        if ((a_data.getTabbedPane() == this)
                && (a_data.getTabIndex() == next
                || next - a_data.getTabIndex() == 1)) {
            m_lineRect.setRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
            m_isDrawRect = false;
        } else if (getTabCount() == 0) {
            m_lineRect.setRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
            m_isDrawRect = false;
            return;
        } else if (next == 0) {
            Rectangle rect = getBoundsAt(0);
            m_lineRect.setRect(-LINEWIDTH / 2, rect.y, LINEWIDTH, rect.height);
            m_isDrawRect = true;
        } else if (next == getTabCount()) {
            Rectangle rect = getBoundsAt(getTabCount() - 1);
            m_lineRect.setRect(rect.x + rect.width - LINEWIDTH / 2, rect.y,
                    LINEWIDTH, rect.height);
            m_isDrawRect = true;
        } else {
            Rectangle rect = getBoundsAt(next - 1);
            m_lineRect.setRect(rect.x + rect.width - LINEWIDTH / 2, rect.y,
                    LINEWIDTH, rect.height);
            m_isDrawRect = true;
        }
    }

    private void initTargetTopBottomLine(int next, TabTransferData a_data) {
        if (next < 0) {
            m_lineRect.setRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
            m_isDrawRect = false;
            return;
        } // if

        if ((a_data.getTabbedPane() == this)
                && (a_data.getTabIndex() == next
                || next - a_data.getTabIndex() == 1)) {
            m_lineRect.setRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
            m_isDrawRect = false;
        } else if (getTabCount() == 0) {
            m_lineRect.setRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
            m_isDrawRect = false;
            return;
        } else if (next == getTabCount()) {
            Rectangle rect = getBoundsAt(getTabCount() - 1);
            m_lineRect.setRect(rect.x, rect.y + rect.height - LINEWIDTH / 2,
                    rect.width, LINEWIDTH);
            m_isDrawRect = true;
        } else if (next == 0) {
            Rectangle rect = getBoundsAt(0);
            m_lineRect.setRect(rect.x, -LINEWIDTH / 2, rect.width, LINEWIDTH);
            m_isDrawRect = true;
        } else {
            Rectangle rect = getBoundsAt(next - 1);
            m_lineRect.setRect(rect.x, rect.y + rect.height - LINEWIDTH / 2,
                    rect.width, LINEWIDTH);
            m_isDrawRect = true;
        }
    }

    private void initGlassPane(Component c, Point tabPt, int a_tabIndex) {
        //Point p = (Point) pt.clone();
        getRootPane().setGlassPane(s_glassPane);
        if (hasGhost()) {
            Rectangle rect = getBoundsAt(a_tabIndex);
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(c.getWidth(),
                    c.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
            c.paint(g);
            image = image.getSubimage(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
            s_glassPane.setImage(image);
        } // if

        s_glassPane.setPoint(buildGhostLocation(tabPt));
        s_glassPane.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Rectangle getTabAreaBound() {
        Rectangle lastTab = getUI().getTabBounds(this, getTabCount() - 1);
        return new Rectangle(0, 0, getWidth(), lastTab.y + lastTab.height);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (m_isDrawRect) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setPaint(m_lineColor);
            g2.fill(m_lineRect);
        } // if
    }

    public interface TabAcceptor {

        boolean isDropAcceptable(DnDCloseButtonTabbedPane a_component, int a_index);
    }
}

class GhostGlassPane extends JPanel {

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final AlphaComposite m_composite;

    private Point m_location = new Point(0, 0);

    private BufferedImage m_draggingGhost = null;

    public GhostGlassPane() {
        setOpaque(false);
        m_composite = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.7f);
    }

    public void setImage(BufferedImage draggingGhost) {
        m_draggingGhost = draggingGhost;
    }

    public void setPoint(Point a_location) {
        m_location.x = a_location.x;
        m_location.y = a_location.y;
    }

    public int getGhostWidth() {
        if (m_draggingGhost == null) {
            return 0;
        } // if

        return m_draggingGhost.getWidth(this);
    }

    public int getGhostHeight() {
        if (m_draggingGhost == null) {
            return 0;
        } // if

        return m_draggingGhost.getHeight(this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (m_draggingGhost == null) {
            return;
        } // if 

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setComposite(m_composite);

        g2.drawImage(m_draggingGhost, (int) m_location.getX(), (int) m_location.getY(), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is all of this code necessary, or can you write a [shorter version](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the problem you're dealing with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement draggable tab using Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60269/how-to-implement-draggable-tab-using-java-swing)

Comment: See also [DragTabFrame closing inconsistently](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18587746/418556).

Comment: Shorter version, can i have my tab drag to desktop / outside JFrame and automatic create JFrame & Tabbedpane ? I also include in my question. thanks for your notif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, After 3 days fighting in 1 file. I Found a way. Still i extend my version of DnD from first link in question.

in DragDropEnd function (Overrides)

```
        @Override
        public void dragDropEnd(DragSourceDropEvent e) {
            m_isDrawRect = false;
            m_lineRect.setRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
            // m_dragTabIndex = -1;

            if (hasGhost()) {
                s_glassPane.setVisible(false);
                s_glassPane.setImage(null);
            }

            // if drop failed, create new JFrame with JTabbedPane included with public access
            if(!e.getDropSuccess()){
                // MenuLight class Extends JFrame and Included 1 component JTabbedPane called superPane
                MenuLight m = new MenuLight();
                m.setLocation(e.getLocation());
                m.setVisible(true);

                // after create Frame, transfer the tab to other jtabbedpane
                ((DnDCloseButtonTabbedPane) m.superPane).convertTab(getTabTransferData(e), getTargetTabIndex(e.getLocation()));
            }

            // if current JTabbedPane Tab is empty dispose it.
            if(getTabCount() < 1){
                // unfortunly i didnt want to close my Original menu, so check the class of parent of DnD is create from MenuLight and dispose it
                if(parent.getClass().equals(MenuLight.class)){
                    ((javax.swing.JFrame) parent).dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

Also it needed to find parent to close immediately if jtabbedpane is close i need to pass the parent form too. So i change the constructor into this.

```
public DnDCloseButtonTabbedPane(final Component _parent)
```

If you want to know MenuLight code, i included it too

```
public class MenuLight extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public MenuLight() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        superPane = new com.theflavare.minierp.helper.DnDCloseButtonTabbedPane(this);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(640, 480));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(superPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 640, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(superPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 480, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    public javax.swing.JTabbedPane superPane;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

And Viola, my mission success, make jtabbedpane drag out and automatic create JFrame. also Dispose the JFrame if current JTabbedpane are empty.

Thx. R